# How to install and run MySQL in Unix environment using the binary file?

Tags: mysql, unix

This is the link I tried.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-installation.html

But an error came at below lines and I am using MySQL 5.7.5

```
shell> bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql    # Before MySQL 5.7.6
```

Error:

```
2016-01-19 12:00:20 [ERROR]   The data directory needs to be specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the datadir location,
for instance,

```
shell>bin>mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=./data
```